# CME Error :10 - Sim not inserted error in SIM800 GSM Module

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command

I get +CME ERROR: 10 on setting AT+COPS=1 
Below is my terminal AT command output:

```
AT
OK 

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 12,0
OK

AT+CMEE=1 
OK

AT+COPS=?
+COPS: (2,"405800","405800","405800"),(1,"40505","40505","40505"),(‌​‌​1,"AirTel","AirTel‌​",‌​"40410"),(1," IDEA CELLULAR Ltd","IDEA","40404"),,(0-4),(0-2) 
OK 

AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0 
OK 

AT+COPS=1
+CME 
ERROR: 10 

AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0 
OK I have a IDEA sim
```

Let me know what is the issue.
I am using around 4 v current. Is it ok?

Comment: My answer may seem dull, but check whether your sim card is inserted properly.

Your error is definitely not a result of low voltage, because in that case the device would rather reboot.

Comment: The problem is still Open

Comment: Same issue for me. Sim card inserted properly and able to get network list successfully.

Comment: I have the same issue with SIM800L? ......

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Same issue, could not find any solution so far. I'm using a Raspberry PI 4 and following here for the cable connections https://www.teachmemicro.com/how-to-send-sms-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 2):

SIM status and presence:

First enable the extended error codes to get a verbose format,

```
AT+CMEE=2
OK
```

Now get the status of SIM presense,

```
AT+cpin?
+CME ERROR: SIM not inserted
```

Above AT command response indicates that SIM card is not present. Verify that SIM is inserted properly and check again,

```
AT+cpin?
+CPIN: READY
OK
```

When the SIM card is ready, above AT response will be received from the module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if you are already connected and registered to the network (CREG status). For better error interpretation send AT+CMEE=2 for verbose errors.